# Conditional SUM within VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Large excel data which looks like this:

[image: Small sample of data]

Now I have to create a macro for my data to filter. The filtration process is as follows:

First select the operator = mum and then select price as 1 and get sum of count column and then 2 and get sum of count column and so on....

then select operator = delhi and similarly select price as 1 and get sum of count column and then 2 and get sum of count column and so on

Comment: Record Macro then generalise and optimise.

Answer (score 0):

For *mum*,

```
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 1, f:f, "mum")
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 2, f:f, "mum")
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 3, f:f, "mum")
...
```

For *dehli*,

```
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 1, f:f, "dehli")
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 2, f:f, "dehli")
=sumifs(c:c, d:d, 3, f:f, "dehli")
...
```

In VBA,

```
dim i as long, j as long, op as variant

op = array("mum", "dehli")

for i=lbound(op) to ubound(op)
    for j=1 to application.max(range("d:d"))
        debug.print application.sumifs(range("c:c"), range("d:d"), j, range("f:f"), op(i))
    next j
next i
```